# Using SELECT...FOR UPDATE, then updating multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I'm writing an application to:

- select a small recordset from a table of subscribers (150k records);
- update those rows to indicate that an email is in the process of being sent;
- send email to the subscribers in the recordset;
- update the rows again to indicate that the email has been sent.

The wrinkle is that the table is simultaneously being accessed by multiple clients to distribute the email workload, which is why there is the intermediate update (to indicate in-process) is used -- to keep the different clients from selecting the same rows, which results in multiple emails being sent to the same subscriber. I've applied some randomizing logic to reduce the likelihood of two clients working with the same data, but it still happens occasionally.

So now I am looking at using SELECT ... FOR UPDATE in order to lock the relevant rows (so another client won't select them). My question: is it better to write the UPDATE statement based on the IDs of the `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` statement, or to create a loop to update each row individually?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`mydef`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_SubscribersToSend`(v_limit INTEGER)
BEGIN

START TRANSACTION;

SELECT _ID, email, date_entered, DATE_FORMAT(date_entered, '%b %e, %Y') AS 'date_entered_formatted'
FROM _subscribers
WHERE send_state = 'Send'
AND status = 'Confirmed'
LIMIT v_limit
FOR UPDATE;

[[UPDATE _subscribers SET send_state = 'Sending' WHERE _ID IN (...?)]]

[[OR]]

[[Loop through the resultset and update each row?]]
COMMIT;

END
```

Seems like a single UPDATE is going to be more efficient; what is the best way to turn the `_ID` column of the resultset into a comma-delimited list for the `IN()` clause? (I've been doing this client-side before this)  -- or is there a better way altogether?

Comment: The rows being updated are the same in both cases. Reducing the number of queries is generally preferable, although I don't know how much difference it makes when the queries are coming from a stored procedure.

Comment: To use the comma-delimited list, you need to concatenate them into a string, then use `PREPARE` to create a query from a string.

Comment: yeah, makes sense. I looked at using `GROUP_CONCAT`, but it seems like that is best suited when only one row is being returned (?), whereas the resultset needs to have multiple rows. So--assuming there are records in the resultset--is the best approach to create a loop and concatenate the `_ID` values? I've not done SQL loops before... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Barmar, I took a different tack in the stored procedure:

```
SET @IDs := null;

UPDATE _subscribers
SET send_state = 'Sending'
WHERE send_state = 'Send'
AND status = 'Confirmed'
AND (SELECT @IDs := CONCAT_WS(',', _ID, @IDs) )
LIMIT v_limit;

SELECT CONVERT(@IDs USING utf8);
```

As Barmar suggested, it does an `UPDATE` but also concatenates the IDs of the rows being updated into a variable. Just `SELECT` that variable, and it gives you a comma-delimited list that can be passed into a `PREPARE` statement. (I had to use `CONVERT` because `SELECT`ing the variable was returning a binary/blob value).  So...this does not use `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` as I was originally intending, but it does ensure that the different clients won't be working with the same rows.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to create a comma-delimited list, just do an `UPDATE` with the same criteria as the `SELECT`

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE _subscribers
SET send_state = 'Sending'
WHERE send_state = 'Send'
AND status = 'Confirmed'
ORDER BY <something>
LIMIT v_limit;

SELECT _ID, email, date_entered, DATE_FORMAT(date_entered, '%b %e, %Y') AS 'date_entered_formatted'
FROM _subscribers
WHERE send_state = 'Send'
AND status = 'Confirmed'
ORDER BY <something>
LIMIT v_limit;

COMMIT;
```

The `ORDER BY` clause is necessary to ensure that both queries process the same rows; if you use `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`, they could select a different subset of rows.